# Prepared statements for building a URL in PHP

Tags: php, prepared-statement, urlencode, urldecode

When building a URL, you can use urldecode and urlencode to escape specific strings, but I'm trying to build strings of the form:

```
$url = "/myobject/id=$id/property=$property"
```

and so on. I have quite a number of these "URL building" statements in my application, and I don't want to have to remember to put urlencode around every single variable in each URL.

In PHP (and other languages) you can safely build a SQL query using a prepared statement. For example:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);
```

The purpose here is to escape any nasty characters in $firstname, $lastname or $email.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do something similar. The code I'm looking for is something like:

```
$url = safe_build_url("/myobject/id=?/property=?", $id, $property)
```

I could use printf to build strings like this, but they aren't escaped property. I could also use urlencode on the whole $url variable, but that loses slashes I want to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for that:

```
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data); // foo=bar&baz=boom&php=hypertext+processor
```

Using the `$encType` param you can even choose the type of urlencoding to be used. If you want it in the same way as `urlencode()` then select `PHP_QUERY_RFC3986` for the `$enctype`. (It is not the default).

Comment: This is great. I can also use the `arg_separator` option to specify slashes instead of ampersands.

Comment: Yeah it is quite helpful and more than a nice to have. It *should* be used for that purpose.